# jquery variable passing error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I got a button name "modify" and when clicked got the value of it by the following

```
 $('button[name=modify]').click(function() {

        alert("button value that you click "+$(this).val());
        mybuttonvalue=$(this).val();
        alert("mybuttonvalue @ button click "+mybuttonvalue);
        $( "#mydialog" ).dialog( "open" );

    })
```

and the variable called "mybuttonvalue" is declared after document is ready and used at the model dialog form' open method as follow

```
  open:function(){
                alert(mybuttonvalue);
                alert($('#ztitle'+mybuttonvalue).val());
                alert($('#znews'+mybuttonvalue).val());
            $('#title').val($('#ztitle'+mybuttonvalue).val());              
            $('#news').val($('#znews'+mybuttonvalue).val());
        },
```

at this point the value of the variable is always 0.
can someone point me out where did i make wrong. plz? thanks

Comment: Where are you setting the value of the button?  Show us your HTML.

Comment: $msg.=" <div id='divPostControl'>
       <button id='modify' name='modify' value='".$newsid."' class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all'>Modify</button>
       <button id='delete' name='delete' value='".$newsid."' class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all'>Delete</button>
      </div>";


this is part of html form and it is repeating.

Comment: @yas You can edit your post and add that in there with formatting so looks better :)  Also can you show the generated HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set variables in one function and use them in another.

Instead, query the value in the function where you need it:

```
$('button[name=modify]').click(function() {
  $( "#mydialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

and

```
open:function(){
  var mybuttonvalue = $('button[name=modify]').val();

  alert($('#ztitle'+mybuttonvalue).val());
  alert($('#znews'+mybuttonvalue).val());

  $('#title').val($('#ztitle'+mybuttonvalue).val());              
  $('#news').val($('#znews'+mybuttonvalue).val());
},
```

Another variant of doing it is discussed here: [jquery-ui, Use dialog('open') and pass a variable to the DIALOG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889877/jquery-ui-use-dialogopen-and-pass-a-variable-to-the-dialog)

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
open:function(){
                alert($('button[name=modify]').val())
            $('#title').val($('#ztitle'+mybuttonvalue).val());              
            $('#news').val($('#znews'+mybuttonvalue).val());
        },
```