# jquery ui dialog change position after first click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I am using jquery `uimodaldialog` and this is setting

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen : false,
    minWidth : 700,
    show : {
        effect : "fade",
        duration : 1000
           },
    hide : {
        effect : "fade",
        duration : 1000
           },
    close : function(event, ui) {
    },
});
```

I am calling with this

```
 $('.mylink').on('click', function() {
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open");
```

Now on first click it shows at center of page .

if I click again then it goes about 200px upwards.

On further clicking it says there

Comment: Does the content of $( "#dialog" ) element changes in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **HTML**

```
<input type="button" class="mylink" />
<div id="dialog">Hello</div>
```

## **jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        minWidth: 700,
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 1000
        },
        position: {
            my: "center",
            at: "center",
            of: window
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {},
    });
    $('.mylink').on('click', function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/k4LLM/1/

Reference http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

Comment: i don't know but i tried same coding puting in my files. First time it displays at correct position but next time display about 200px upwards. any idea which thing have been iterfering

Comment: can i add position with `.dialog('open')` so that i gets value from there not from default

Comment: [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889877/jquery-ui-use-dialogopen-and-pass-a-variable-to-the-dialog) this might help you

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the position of dialog by following code

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
autoOpen : false,
minWidth : 700,
position: { 
    my: 'top',
    at: 'top',
    of: $('#some_div')
  }
show : {
    effect : "fade",
    duration : 1000
},
hide : {
    effect : "fade",
    duration : 1000
},
close : function(event, ui) {
},
});
```

You can find help about jquery position at http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Comment: i try that but first time postion is right like defined , then next time is upwards than previous position

Comment: what value you have set for my , at and of ?

Comment: same as yours , is there any way to add postion with dailog.open

Answer (score 0):

If you have dynamic height of contents in it. I think dialog can be changed second click.
for solving it, use height option of dialog.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen : false,
    minWidth : 700,
    height : 500, //it should be size of your contents
    show : {
        effect : "fade",
        duration : 1000
           },
    hide : {
        effect : "fade",
        duration : 1000
           },
    close : function(event, ui) {
    },
});
```